# How do I change character classes in Firefall?

Tags: firefall

Is there a way to change characters in Firefall? Or are you stuck permanently with the one picked upon Character Setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands you can only create 1 character, but there is no need to create more than 1 anyhow.

Each character can swap between any of the Battleframes (Firefall's version of a 'Class'), simply by unlocking it at the battleframe garage and then swapping between them by using the battleframe stations (these are located in most towns/outposts/watch towers)

You start with 3 battleframe slots, and can purchase more with redbeans (the ingame currency), but even if you dont wish to spend anything on purchasing any extra slots, you can happily delete battleframes without losing any XP or unlocks you have earned on each frame. Meaning you can delete a frame, and later load that frame again and you still have everything you had originally... you will just have to re-equip certain gear items/unlocks.

Comment: I should add you can also change your appearance any time at the 'new you' stations scattered about.